# Is it possible to visualize gradients in comet-ml?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, comet-ml

It is straightforward to set up TensorBoard in Keras (it's just a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard)!) and then it is possible to visualize the distribution and magnitude of the weights and gradients. Is it possible to do the same with [comet.ml](https://www.comet.ml)? Comet.ml is easy to set up, but visualizes only the loss and accuracy evolution... Is there a way to "restore" all the TensorBoard features in comet.ml?